# Solving Mixed-Integer Non-Linear Optimization Problem

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, combinatorial-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I would like to solve the following optimization problem:

\begin{array}{ll}
\underset{x_{i}\geq0,\, \pi_{i}\in\{0,1\}}{\text{minimize}} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n  x_i\\ 
\text{subject to} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \pi_{i}\Big(\frac{q}{d+d \exp(ab-as_ix_i)}-c\Big) \geq t\\ 
&\sum x_i \leq l, . 
\end{array}

where $q,d,a,b,c,t,\text{and} ~l$ are real positive scalars and $s_1>s_2>…>s_n>0$.

The problem is non-convex due to the coupled binary variable and the sigmoid function in the first constraint. Also, if the binary variables $\pi_i$ are removed the problem still non-convex due the sum-of-ratio in the first constraint. How to solve this problem with\without the binary variables.

Comment: What value does n have?  If not too big, perhaps BARON https://www.minlp.com/baron or BMIBNB under YALMIP https://yalmip.github.io/solver/bmibnb/ will work?  If you can settle for a local minimum, you can try KNITRO. https://www.artelys.com/en/optimization-tools/knitro .  if you know a feasible solution, that may help the optimizers. All of the above can do with or without binary restriction.

Comment: Normally, n<10.

Comment: For n < 10, my advice is to try a global optimizer, such as listed in my previous comment.